# How do I change the title bar buttons on Kubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, customization, window, titlebar

I'm thinking about making some custom buttons for the window title bar (close, maximize, etc.) for Kubuntu 13.10. The problem is that I can't figure out what files I'm supposed to be editing to do this. Could someone please tell me what files I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

In KDE GUI apps do most of the things you need. Just open `systemsettings` app and move into `Workspace Apperance`. In section `Window Decorations` there is a button called `Configure Buttons` click on it there is all you need.

Comment: All I see are options for changing button position and order. What I'm trying to do is create my own buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends**

The Kubuntu is using the KDE desktop. The KDE supports many window decorations. The window decoration has the appearance of window borders, titlebars and buttons.

Some window styles are supported by the standard installation - Aurorae theme. Some window decorations will need an external engine - deKorator.

[image]

**Few examples**

**Aurorae**

The Aurore theme is using the svg images. The Aurorae from the KDE TechBase: http://techbase.kde.org/User:Mgraesslin/Aurorae

From the KDE Forum: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=110835

**deKorator**

The deKorator:

```
:~$ apt-cache show kwin-style-dekorator
Description: Windows decoration engine for KDE 4 using user-supplied PNG files
 With deKorator, easily create your own window decoration for KDE 4!
 deKorator uses your own made images for buttons, borders and so on.
 Go ahead and be creative!
 An example called uglyTheme is provided to show its possibilities.
 .
 Themes can be created by the user with the help of a drawing program or can be
 downloaded from http://www.kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=21
```

[image]